# How to check if Paramiko SFTP client is still open

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, sftp, paramiko

How do I check sftp client opened earlier via Paramiko is still active throughout

```
self.sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

My application logic at times keeps the SFTP connection idle from anywhere between 0.5 sec to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** This answer is only related to see if the **SFTPClient** object created after calling `open_sftp()` is still open and not to check if the paramiko ssh connection is still alive.

You can have access to this information using the sock attribute of the connection.

```py
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.sock.closed
>>> False

# closing the connection
sftp.close()
sftp.sock.closed
>>> True
```

Alternatively you can also have a try except approach to see if the connection is still open or not.

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

try:
    sftp.listdir()
except OSError as e:
    # connection is closed
    # handle the exception
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can try testing `ssh.get_transport().is_active()`, the only sure way is to try to use the connection.

---

But you can make Paramiko keep the connection alive:
[Python Paramiko SSH session not active after being idle for many hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50009688/850848)